# How to get Only particular string from <p> tag element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying so many time but i can't able to success. My question is how to trim particular sting from `<p>` tag element. I wish to output olny- `SSP2019021700035756`.

Example:

```
    <div class="success_bx">

      <p>Your Application id is : SSP2019021700035756 </p>

   </div>
```

Comment: If you try so many time, please show us what you have tried

Comment: If it's a code I recommend using Regular Expressions. String.prototype.match().

Comment: Is there any way to "match" that string?  Eg is it always `SSP\d{16}` or can it be any string?  or is it always SSP2019021700035756?  (in which case `var x = "SSP2019021700035756";`)

Answer (score 2):

You could `split` the string at the `:`and return the second value

`$(".success_bx p").text().split(" : ")[1]` should work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="success_bx">

      <p>Your Application id is : <span id={"myId"}>SSP2019021700035756</span> </p>

   </div>
```

However as Sfili said, usually you should post also the code you tried to implement

Comment: Not sure this warranted a downvote without guidance.  Add a description to say why/how this fixes the problem.  Simply wrapping it in a div doesn't provide an output.

Comment: I downvoted because a) there are curly braces in there and b) this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Having the id he/she can easily access to the content of the tag

Comment: I know, but if the OP can just change the server-side HTML, why would they need to ask this question in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for providing feedback on your downvote.  It's useful to people new to answering.

Comment: *"can [easily] access the content of the tag"* is a valid answer to this question as OP may not have thought of wrapping it (and there are numerous examples in SO of similar questions where that was the accepted answer).  But adding it without a description doesn't say why or *how*.  And 'easily' is of course, subjective.